# Unity - Checking if the player is grounded not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want the player to jump when the player is grounded.

```
private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.layer == 8)
    {
        isGrounded = true;
    }else { isGrounded = false; }
}
```

The player is on air when spawning. After the player falls to the Terrain, which has the tag `Ground`, `isGrounded` is still false. When I set isGrounded manually true and jump again, it's still true after collision. I also don't want the player to double jump in the air, which I probaly already coded but is not working because something is wrong.

Changing `OnTriggerStay` to `OnTriggerEnter` doesn't change something. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Did you check if `other.gameObject.layer` is really 8? put there breakpoint and debug it.

Comment: Yes it is. Making it `other.gameObject.layer.ToString() == "Ground"` still didn't change anything. It doesn't dedect a trigger somehow. The script is attached to the player object.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do **not** use `OnTriggerStay` to do this. That's not guaranteed to be true very time.

Set isGrounded flag to true when `OnCollisionEnter` is called. Set it to false when `OnCollisionExit` is called.

```
bool isGrounded = true;

private float jumpForce = 2f;
private Rigidbody pRigidBody;

void Start()
{
    pRigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
    {
        pRigidBody.AddForce(new Vector3(0, jumpForce, 0));
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    Debug.Log("Entered");
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
    {
        isGrounded = true;
    }
}

void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
{
    Debug.Log("Exited");
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
    {
        isGrounded = false;
    }
}
```

Before you say it doesn't work, please check the following:

- You must have `Rigidbody` or `Rigidbody2D` attached to the player.
- If this `Rigidbody2D`, you must use `OnCollisionEnter2D` and
  `OnCollisionExit2D`.
- You must have Collider attached to the player with IsTrigger
  disabled.
- Make sure you are not moving the `Rigidbody` with the transform such
  as `transform.position` and `transform.Translate`. You must move
  `Rigidbody` with the [`MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) function.

Comment: I removed all codes except for `player.AddForce(new Vector3(0, jumpForce, 0));` but the player doesn't jump. Seems like the player is not jumping. I am using Unity 5.5.1

Answer (score 0):

Use this to check if collision is detected at all, it's good starting point for further debuging:

```
private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
   Debug.Log(other);
}
```

Comment: It's not dedected somehow. I gave the script the player object.

Comment: Are you sure you have added Collider component to both objects ?

Comment: Yes, the `Ground` object is a terrain with terrain collider.

Answer (score 0):

You must have Collider attached to the player with IsTrigger disabled.

I think you mean enabled? I was struggling to get this to work but as soon as I enabled the collider's IsTrigger it started actually working. The OnTriggerEnter/Exit doesn't seem to do very much on a collider that isn't actually a trigger...