# How can I make a game object jump when I press a key (preferably space)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this C# script attached to my main camera game object which also has a capsule collider attribute. However, it doesn't seem to do anything. How should I modify/add to this to make the camera "jump" and fall down to the ground again?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Jump : MonoBehaviour {


    [HideInInspector] public bool jump = false;
    public float jumpForce = 1000f;
    public Transform groundCheck;


    private bool grounded = false;
    private Rigidbody rb;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake () 
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        grounded = Physics2D.Linecast(transform.position, groundCheck.position, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ground"));

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && grounded)
        {
            jump = true;
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        if (jump)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpForce));
            jump = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I would like to have the key for this be the spacebar if possible, but whatever key works or is there already is fine. I am still learning C#, so please forgive me if the solution is obvious.

Comment: I understand you have a code in your question but I have a feeling you did not write that due to the way the question is asked. I suggest you learn how Unity works. Just follow any of their [project tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials) and you will be able to start writing your own code.

Comment: As for changing the key that should be pressed, use `KeyCode.Space`.  You can see example of jumping from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44539475/3785314) post. Although, it won't work if you don't know how to setup layer and put the ground in the correct layer.

Comment: @Programmer I have put the ground in the ground layer. Where would I use KeyCode.Space though? Is there a place to set which key is used?

Answer (score 1):

This line is most likely causing the problem:

```
grounded = Physics2D.Linecast(transform.position, groundCheck.position, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ground"));`
```

There are 2 reason that it wont produce proper results:

1. You haven't setup your ground tiles or the place where you character moves to the "Ground" layer. You wont have this by default but you can add it from the Project Settings->Tags and Layers menu.
2. Your colliders are not close enough to the ground thus not causing collision.

Besides that it should work fine.