# Check if bool is true for atleast x time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently I have a raycast setup that checks if the player is grounded and can jump. In some cases this groundcheck can be true, but the landing animation has not yet finished. For this reason I would like to do something like if isGrounded is true for at least x seconds/frames do something. How would one achieve this check?

```
void JumpRun()
{
    if (JumpCheck())
    {
        float jumpVelocity = Mathf.Sqrt(-2 * gravity * jumpHeight);
        velocityY = jumpVelocity;
        anim.SetTrigger("JumpRun");
        canJump = Time.time + 0f; //Delay after jump input
    }
}

private bool JumpCheck()
{
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector3.down * distanceForJump, Color.red);

    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, distanceForJump))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Start timer when bool is true. At the end of the timer, check if bool is still true. Nothing complicated. If you still have issues, modify your question with your code from what I said above

Comment: Wow that is quick response, I have no clue how to write a check like that, will update the question with my relevant code.

Comment: Where is the `isGrounded` part of the code? That's relevant here

Comment: Yeah for jumping I have used the words JumpCheck, which is my groundCheck,

Comment: Instead of doing that, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44539237/unity-checking-if-the-player-is-grounded-not-working/44539475#44539475) for your grounded check

Comment: I use a character controller component instead of a physics based third person controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167005/discussion-between-quincy-norbert-and-programmer).

Comment: Ok. I will leave answer when I am back on my PC. If you get answer from another person and it works, I will upvote it

Comment: Thanks, I will keep track of this topic.

Comment: Where can I see the answer? I have no idea how to write the timer. Ah totally missed it, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start timer when `JumpCheck()` function and a jump `flag` are both `true`. Before the timer, set that flag to `false` so that it cannot jump again. At the end of the timer, set the flag to `true` again. There are just many ways to do this. This is just one of them. In the example below, the flag is `readyToJumpAgain`. The default value should be `true`.

```
bool readyToJumpAgain = true;

void JumpRun()
{
    if (JumpCheck() && readyToJumpAgain)
    {
        float jumpVelocity = Mathf.Sqrt(-2 * gravity * jumpHeight);
        velocityY = jumpVelocity;
        anim.SetTrigger("JumpRun");
        //Start a timer that waits for 4 seconds
        StartCoroutine(waitForAnimation(4f));
    }
}

private IEnumerator waitForAnimation(float time)
{
    readyToJumpAgain = false;
    //Wait for x seconds
    yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(time);
    //Ready to jump again
    readyToJumpAgain = true;
}
```

Comment: This is indeed working for delaying the jump, but I have not figured out how to implement this when the user is not jumping, but falling. However, this should be possible with the current code.

Comment: What do you mean when the user is not jumping? I think you should explain the current behavior and what you expect

Comment: I had implemented it only when the jump button was pressed. For this reason the delay only worked when the jump button was pressed. There are cases though, where the player doesn't press the jump button, and walks of an edge. On that check I didn't add the coroutines, and thats why it didn't work.